# Javascript Issue in Custom Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck with a JavaScript issue in the following plugin. I am getting the below error when I tried to reload the page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at (index):1141
(index):1161 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):1161)
    at i (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js:2)
```

I am adding the code link (It's a plugin). So can you guys help me to find a solution for this?

```
https://pastebin.com/KSPPX57j
```

The issue happens when I tried to install this PHP code(custom created plugin). I was not aware of the jQuery syntax since I am newbie to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix will be to simply replace `$(` to `jQuery(`

Comment: Can you please replace the same? since I have some confusion with variable $ in javascript also. Please send the link in Pastebin. It will help me.. Thanks

Comment: @DeepeshKumar why dont you accept my answer then. :-)

Comment: @DeepeshKumar well, I mean you can click "Check" icon besides my answer to accept.